# Find an enum inside unordered_map and get its value?

Tags: c++

Given the following code:

```
enum Keys {
    Up,
    Down,
    Left,
    Right
};

enum KeyState {
    Down,
    Up
};

std::unordered_map<Keys, KeyState> keys;

keys[Keys::Up] = KeyState::Up;
keys[Keys::Down] = KeyState::Up;
keys[Keys::Left] = KeyState::Down;
keys[Keys::Right] = KeyState::Up;
```

How can i write a method like this:

```
isKeyDown(Keys key) {
   return true if key has the Up or Down state.
}
```

Comment: (and learn at least the basics of C++.)

Comment: @H2CO3 Well, the question isn't a complete loss: I found out that there may be a specialization for `std::hash<E>` where `E` is any `enum` by default!  Neat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
KeyState value = keys[key];
return value == KeyState::Up || value == KeyState::Down;
```

Of course, those are the only two values you have defined for `KeyState`, so, as it stands...

```
return true;
```

Comment: What if the value does not exist?

Comment: @vinnylinux: He populated the map with all possible (valid) keys beforehand. Besides, is that really the important bit here, handling all possible error conditions? Do I really need to account for `isKeyDown((KeyState)INT_MAX);` in example code?